# Undo "take server version" of project file

Tags: tfs

I did a GET and stupidly took the server version of the project file I was working on. I had made many additions and changes to the project (ie adding directories and files) that are now no longer showing up in my solution explorer, but the files are still on the file system.

Is there any way I can undo "just" the project file "take server version" so I can do a proper merge?

Comment: I did this too and lost the code that took me one day to write! @microsoft do something about this ...

Comment: the same problem :(  Microsoft should do something about that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't undo the get; the version with your modifications has been overwritten.  You can, however, add all the files back into the project.  The easiest way is usually to enable 'Show All Files' and then for each missing file you can do 'Include in project'.

Comment: I was hoping this would not be the case but I think you are right. I tried reverting the project file to the last version but it didn't work and besides I think that would have made things even worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one thing, in case your concerned file in the solution explorer is not yet closed try undo and keep doing it (Ctrl + Z) and **it may** help you restore your data.

Comment: I don't think that would work on a project file... My actual code files were fine, automerged or unchanged, but the project file... not so much

Answer (score 0):

I am answering late, but this may help someone....
In your Solution Explorer, right click the file you accidentally took Server version of, and then select preview changes to {file name}. You will see your changes there.

Comment: you can do it only when the file checked out (before the action of taking server version)